# How do I log in to my Game Center with nickname?

Tags: apple-id, game-center

I created an account some time ago and I could sign in through a username. I have the correct password and username but it took me a few tries to remember. The account got locked and it tells me to go to the Apple ID website to recover the account. I have to type in my Apple ID but I cannot because the username isn't an Apple ID.

[image]

[image] [image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your nickname is not your AppleID. Sign in with your AppleID.

Comment: im trying to get my old data and not start a new one

Comment: Your nickname has to be assigned to an existing Apple ID... that's what you need to sign in to.

Comment: it was never assigned to an apple id it was only a username

Comment: You have to have an Apple ID; you can't have a nickname, or an app, or an iPhone, or....  without one.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I was giving problems I got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Your nickname is not your Apple ID. Sign in with your Apple ID.